# Swift Dictionary of Types / Generics

Tags: swift

I am trying to define a dictionary of metatypes in Swift. The metatypes all descend from a known base class, and each must be registered with a string value that is unique to each metatype.

I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
  private struct Registry {
    static let map: Dictionary = [String: Foo.Type]()
  }

  class func registerType<T: Foo>(typeId: String, classType: T.Type) {
    Registry.map[typeId] = classType
  }
}
```

However, this is returning an error message in the "registerType" method:

```
'@lvalue $T6' is not identical to '(String, Foo.Type)'
```

How can I create a dictionary of metatypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your `map` dictionary with `var` instead of `let` so that it can be updated:

```
static var map: Dictionary = [String: Foo.Type]()
```